# How to group a header of a fasta file

Tags: python, regex

The headers of my fasta file look like this:

```
>ref|NC_001133| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=I]

>ref|NC_001134| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=II]

>ref|NC_001135| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=III]

>ref|NC_001136| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=IV]

>ref|NC_001137| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=V]

>ref|NC_001138| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=VI]

>ref|NC_001139| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=VII]

>ref|NC_001140| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=VIII]

>ref|NC_001141| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=IX]

>ref|NC_001142| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=X]

>ref|NC_001143| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=XI]

>ref|NC_001144| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=XII]

>ref|NC_001145| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=XIII]

>ref|NC_001146| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=XIV]

>ref|NC_001147| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=XV]

>ref|NC_001148| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=XVI]

>ref|NC_001224| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [location=mitochondrion] [top=circular]
```

I need to replace each corresponding `>ref|NC_001133|` for the respective location e.g.'[chromosome=I]' because I want to get a proper format for the upcoming runs, but first I want to group each section of the header using regular expressions; however, in the last line, the section of the mitochondria complicates me to group each item properly. I really hope you could help grouping by using regex.

This is a portion of my code that I was trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import re
import subprocess
from sys import argv

def get_fasta_rec(input_fasta):
        """Find all FASTA entries in a FASTA file, change the headers and return them in a dictionary.

        input_fasta -- FASTA file name
        record_dict -- dict, {header:seq}
        """
        entries = input_fasta.split(">")[1:]
        dict_entry = {}
        for entry in entries:
                header, x, seq = entry.partition("\n")
                m = re.search("(.+) (.+\s.+) (.+) (.+) (.+|('[location=mitochondrion] [top=circular]'))", header)

                if m:
                    ref = m.group(1)

                    org = m.group(2)

                    strain = m.group(3)

                    moltype = m.group(4)

                    location = m.group(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        input_fasta = open(argv[1]).read()
        get_fasta_rec(input_fasta)
```

The output I would like to get for each header is:

```
> [chromosome=I] [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [ref|NC_001133|]
> [location=mitochondrion] [top=circular] [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [ref|NC_001224|]
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you please show what is the output you would like to get?

Comment: Thanks, alec_dijnn, I already re-edited my post.

Comment: How would the mitochondrion one look like?

Comment: The pattern could be a bit optimized using  a negated character class. Then make the last part optional. `(>ref\|NC_\d+\|) (\[[^[\]]+\]) (\[[^[\]]+\]) (\[[^[\]]+\]) (\[[^[\]]+\])(?:( \[[^[\]]+\]))?` https://regex101.com/r/p3PuLG/1/ Perhaps you might also split on a space. To get the last part with one or 2 items: https://regex101.com/r/K99fqY/1

Comment: @SilviaVC Do you want to include `location=mitochondrion` in a group and also use in the replacement, or should that line not match? Or only match the ones that start with `[chromosome=`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird  so far I would like to include location=mitochondrion in a group and also use in the replacement but just because I want to keep the formats and don't delete any potentially useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use regex here. Simple string splitting and formatting would work just fine.

```
h = '>ref|NC_001133| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=I]'   
#h = '>ref|NC_001224| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [location=mitochondrion] [top=circular]'

fields = h[1:].split() #[1:] so you skip the >

if len(fields) == 6:
    new_h = [fields[-1]] + fields[1:-1] + [f'[{fields[0]}]']

elif len(fields) == 7: #extra filed for the mitocondrion case
    new_h = [fields[-2]] + fields[1:-2] + [fields[-1]] + [f'[{fields[0]}]']

new_h = f'> {" ".join(new_h)}'

print(new_h)
> [chromosome=I] [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [ref|NC_001133|]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked; however, could you explain to me what the [f'[{fields[0]}]' represent all together.

Comment: String formatting via f-strings. It's just to add the square brackets around the ref field. https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 0):

See [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yMWZyA/1) for an explanation of

`(?:(>ref\|.+\|)\s)?((?:\[[\S\d]+=[^\]]+\])+)\s?`

You'll need to use `re.findall(...)` and your groups of attributes will be in group 2 in each match.

Answer (score 0):

You could optimize the pattern a bit using a negated character class matching any char except a closing square bracket `\[[^[\]]+\]`

In the 5th group you could repeat matching the same patterns to get 1 whole group.

```
(>ref\|NC_\d+\|)( \[[^[\]]+\])( \[[^[\]]+\])( \[[^[\]]+\])( \[[^[\]]+\](?: \[[^[\]]+\])*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4lelG/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PhpifC)

In the replacement use

```
>\5\2\3\4[\1]
```

For example using [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
import re

regex = r"(>ref\|NC_\d+\|)( \[[^[\]]+\])( \[[^[\]]+\])( \[[^[\]]+\])( \[[^[\]]+\](?: \[[^[\]]+\])*)"

test_str = (">ref|NC_001133| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [chromosome=I]\n"
    ">ref|NC_001224| [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic] [location=mitochondrion] [top=circular]")

subst = r">\5\2\3\4[\1]"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str)

print (result)
```

Output

```
> [chromosome=I] [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic][>ref|NC_001133|]
> [location=mitochondrion] [top=circular] [org=Saccharomyces cerevisiae] [strain=S288C] [moltype=genomic][>ref|NC_001224|]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try also this code in my script.